# Keras ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 16) are incompatible

Tags: keras

I'm trying to train a multilabel classification from text input.
I first tokenize the text

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'])
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['text'])
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen)
```

getting the following shape:

> Shape of data tensor: (1333, 100) Shape of label tensor: (1333,)

Then I split in train and validations

```
x_train = data[:training_samples]
y_train = labels[:training_samples]
x_val = data[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]
y_val = labels[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]
```

I use Glove for word representations

```
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join(glove_dir, 'glove.6B.100d.txt'))
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

embedding_dim = 100

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((max_words, embedding_dim))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i < max_words:
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

I build the Keras model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Ending up with

```
Model: "sequential_32"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_27 (Embedding)     (None, 100, 100)          1000000   
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_21 (Flatten)         (None, 10000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_56 (Dense)             (None, 64)                640064    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_57 (Dense)             (None, 16)                1040      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,641,104
Trainable params: 1,641,104
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I set the weigth of the emedding layer:

```
model.layers[0].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

But I end up with the error

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 16) are incompatible

Everything works right if I do a single-label classification (using Dense(1) as last layer and sigmoid activation), but I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Is `y_train` one-hot encoded ?

Comment: No, I didn't do one-hot encode. y_train Is a list of integers between 0 and 15

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve my problem. I think this need to be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your labels into [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) format if you use `categorical_crossentropy`.

Otherwise you can try with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function which accept your format of labels ([info](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)).

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other